# EmptyListBox control doesn't get notified that ItemsSouce changed (silverlight / wp7)

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, listbox, itemssource

Tried may approches to displaying a "no data" if there are no items in listbox. Since I'm on wp7 and using silverlight I can't use DataTriggers, so I've created a control to have it behave consistently across the whole app. BUT I if you set the breakpoint for the set method - it's not being called at all!

The control class

```
public class EmptyListBox : ListBox
{
    public new IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get 
        {
            return base.ItemsSource; 
        }

        set
        {    
            // never here
            base.ItemsSource = value;
            ItemsSourceChanged();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void ItemsSourceChanged()
    {
        bool noItems = Items.Count == 0;

        if (noItems)
        {
            if (Parent is System.Windows.Controls.Panel)
            {
                var p = Parent as Panel;

                TextBlock noData = new TextBlock();
                noData.Text = "No data";
                noData.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment;
                noData.Width = Width;
                noData.Height = Height;
                noData.Margin = Margin;

                p.Children.Add(noData);
                Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is xaml

```
<my:EmptyListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyData}" Name="myListBox">
    <my:EmptyListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </my:EmptyListBox.ItemTemplate>
</my:EmptyListBox>
```

Codebehind:

```
    ClientModel ClientInfo { get; set; }

    public ClientView()
    {
        ClientInfo = new ClientModel();
        ClientInfo.PropertyChanged += new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler(DataReady);

        DataContext = ClientInfo
    }
```

ClientModel class:

```
public class ClientModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    MyData _myData;
    public MyData MyData 
    {
        get
        {
            return _myData;
        }

        set
        {
            _myData = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("MyData");
        }
    }

    public void GetClient(int id)
    {
        // fetch the network for data
    }
}
```

LINK TO SOLUTION .ZIP THAT SHOWS THE PROBLEM

```
http://rapidshare.com/files/455900509/WindowsPhoneDataBoundApplication1.zip
```

Comment: And where are you setting the ItemsSource or DataContext of the page?

Comment: As a recommendation if you're having problems with your code, post all that is relevant to be able to recreate the issue. This includes all custom classes. - What is `MyData`?

Comment: Seriously Matt, this is NOT the issue, as biding _works_. MyData is POCO.

Comment: @argh I was trying to recreate what you are doing. If I'm just guessing at the code you've got then whether I can get my code to work on not is irrelevant.

Comment: ok, sorry, but I just hate those questions - I've created a sample and edited the post

Answer (score 1):

Your new ItemSource should be a DependencyProperty.
Anything that is working with Bindings have to be a DependencyProperty.
Simply make it a DependencyProperty.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but since I'm deriving from ListBox then it should already be a DependencyProperty?

Comment: When you declare dependencyProperty you also specify ownerType.
In your case the ownerType is EmptyListBox.(compared with ItemsControl of original ItemsSource)
you'll need to declare your own DependencyProperty, but seems you tryed and it doesn't help , which is strange.
In any case maybe we have here another problem as well, but the fact that ItemsSource should be a DependencyProperty is for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution I'd go for is something like this:

1. Define a new visual state group **ItemsStates** and two visual states: **NoItems** and **HasItems**.

   1. In the ControlTemplate for your custom listbox, add the visual tree for your "no data" state.
   2. In the **NoItems** state, set the `Visibility` of your "no data" elements to `Visible` and set the `Visibility` of the default `ItemsPresenter` to `Collapsed`.
   3. In the **HasItems** state, swap the `Visibility` of these elements.
   4. In an `OnApplyTemplate` override switch to the **Empty** state by default: `VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Empty", true);`
   5. In an `OnItemsChanged` override, check whether the items source is empty and use `VisualStateManager` to switch between these states accordingly.

That should work :)

Answer (score 0):

Create ItemsSource as a `DependencyProperty`.

Example:

```
 public IEnumerable ItemsSource
 {
   get { return (IEnumerable)base.GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
   set { base.SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
 }

 public static DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ItemsSource",
            typeof(IEnumerable),
            typeof(EmptyListBox),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Comment: this doesn't work... adding 'new' to names also didn't work... notice that I'm inheriting ListBox

Answer (score 0):

try to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface and use for ItemsSource an ObservableCollection. In the Setter of your Property just call the OnPropertyChanged method.

Maybe this will help.

Comment: Client model is inheriting INotifyPropertyChanged and the data populates correctly. The problem is that I don't know why my stuff is not being called.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Mode=TwoWay to the ItemsSource binding:

```
<my:EmptyListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyData, Mode=TwoWay}" Name="myListBox">
    <my:EmptyListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </my:EmptyListBox.ItemTemplate>
</my:EmptyListBox>
```

Comment: didn't work either - binding works, but it looks like the class is ignoring the fact that I've overloaded the ItemsSource in my derived class